# EDITErroneous windows name in opencv

Tags: c++, string, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4.1 with visual studio 11 in windows 8.

I give perfectly legible names to my windows such the followings:

```
namedWindow( "canny_src");
imshow( "canny_src", canny_src );

namedWindow( "canny_other_image");
imshow( "canny_other_image", canny_other );

namedWindow( "RESULT");
imshow( "RESULT", result );
```

But when the windows are open I get very rare name, look by your self:

[image]

Can someone help me to fix

EDIT!!! The entire code here.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "cv.h"
  #include "highgui.h"
  #include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"

  using namespace cv;

  Mat src;
  Mat other;

  int thresh_src = 100;
  int thresh_other = 100;
  int max_thresh = 255;

  void thresh_callback(int, void* );

  int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
    IplImage *_img = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\lena.jpg", 0);
    IplImage *_img_other = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\lena.jpg", 0);
    src = Mat(_img);

    other = Mat(_img_other);


    namedWindow("image");
    imshow("image", src);


    createTrackbar("Tracking src: ", "image", &thresh_src, max_thresh, thresh_callback);
    createTrackbar("Tracking other: ", "image", &thresh_other, max_thresh, thresh_callback);


    waitKey(0);
  }



  void thresh_callback(int, void*)
  {
    Mat canny_src;
    Mat canny_other;
    Mat result;
    Canny(src, canny_src, thresh_src, thresh_src * 2, 3);
    Canny(other, canny_other, thresh_other, thresh_other * 2, 3);

    bitwise_and(canny_src, canny_other, result);


    namedWindow( "canny_src");
    imshow( "canny_src", canny_src );

    namedWindow( "canny_other_image");
    imshow( "canny_other_image", canny_other );

    namedWindow( "RESULT");
    imshow( "RESULT", result );
}
```

Comment: please give the entire code.

Comment: @Abhishek kumar I edited the question adding the entire code. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
setlocale( 0, "" );
```

before any of mentioned by you.

Comment: sorry but I'm not following you. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: What didn't you understand? One more time, before any instruction you have published, put instruction setlocale( 0, "" );

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and ran it on my system. I did not get any erroneous window names. I have attached my output.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error. My imshow windows always had a bugged title, and imread always failed (no img.data).
After some testing, I found out that I had "_DEBUG;" in my preprocessor definitions while running on release. Another error source is the runtime library and mixing debug / release libraries.
Hope this helps someone.